# Spark 2.1.1 with typesafeconfig

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2, typesafe-config

I'm trying to support some external configuration file for my spark application using typesafeconfig.

I'm loading the application.conf file in my application code like this (driver):

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load()
val myProp = config.getString("app.property")
val df = spark.read.avro(myProp)
```

application.conf looks like this:

```
app.propety="some value"
```

spark-submit execution looks like this:

```
spark-submit 
        --class com.myapp.Main \
        --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
        --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
        --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=56 \
        --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=1000 \
        --driver-class-path $HOME/conf/*.conf \
        --files $HOME/conf/application.conf \
        my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

seems it doesn't work and I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'app'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:147)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:206)
    at com.paypal.cfs.fpti.Main$.main(Main.scala:42)
    at com.paypal.cfs.fpti.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:750)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

looking at the logs i do see that "--files" work, seems like a classpath issue...

```
18/03/13 01:08:30 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:/home/user/conf/application.conf at file:/home/user/conf/application.conf with timestamp 1520928510820
18/03/13 01:08:30 INFO Utils: Copying /home/user/conf/application.conf to /tmp/spark-2938fde1-fa4a-47af-8dc6-1c54b5e89d48/userFiles-c2cec57f-18c8-491d-8679-df7e7da45e05/application.conf
```

Comment: It works when I use --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dapp.property=/some/path". Just not sure how to make it read from my file

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was pretty close to the answer to begin with... here is how it worked for me:

```
spark-submit \
    --class com.myapp.Main \
    --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=56 \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=1000 \
    --driver-class-path $APP_HOME/conf \
    --files $APP_HOME/conf/application.conf \
    $APP_HOME/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

then $APP_HOME will contain the below:

```
conf/application.conf
my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I guess you need to make sure the application.conf is placed inside a folder, that is the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify the config file path, you may pass it as an application argument, and then read it from the `args` variable of the main class.

This is how you would execute the spark-submit command. Note that I've specified the config file after the application jar.

```
spark-submit 
        --class com.myapp.Main \
        --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
        --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
        --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=56 \
        --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=1000 \
        my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar $HOME/conf/application.conf
```

And then, load the config file from the path specified in `args(0)`:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
[...]
val dbconfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(args(0))
```

Now you have access to the properties of your `application.conf` file.

```
val myProp = config.getString("app.property")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is not a nice one. it feels like a workaround.